# Unknown how my FreeBSD NAS is synchronizing with another FreeBSD NAS?

Tags: synchronization, cron, rsync, freebsd

I have two FreeBSD (rel 9.3) NAS, I recently took on this new position and found out that these two NAS are synchronizing data (specifically to /mnt/Store folder) but I can't seem to find where/how this is being synced? I have looked in Rsync, /etc/fstab, crontab, but no go.

I know this folder (/mnt/Store) is being synced with another similar NAS because when I SSH into both, the sync does not happen instantly. Whatever file/folder I create in the main NAS, I see the new file/folder on the other NAS replicated a few hours later.

Any suggestions on how I can find out how this is happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Disregard. I found out the sync is scheduled in the Web-GUI (FreeNAS).